# Automate adding host and IP to known hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I wanted to get rid of some warnings I'm getting when running an automated builds environment (Scrutinizer-CI, to be precise).

Digging here, I've found this solution I can add to the script which prepares the container:

`ssh-keyscan -H -p 1234 domain.tld >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

It looks like this is not the best way to do so.
Not sure if that's a matter of security or what, but the warnings about the host is gone.

The problem is that I'm still getting a warning for the IP to which the domain resolve.

I guess that this would sole the problem

`ssh-keyscan -H -p 1234 123.231.321.213 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

But what if I don't know the IP, or if the host does not always resolve to the same IP?

There is some command/script I could write to resolve the IP and pass it to the above script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `dig` to obtain the IPs and then pass them to `ssh-keyscan`.

Example with xargs:

```
dig -t a +short www.yahoo.com | grep ^[0-9] | xargs -r -n1 ssh-keyscan -H -p 1234 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Example with a for loop:

```
for ip in $(dig -t a +short www.yahoo.com | grep ^[0-9]); do ssh-keyscan -H -p 1234 $ip; done >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)

Comment: can you explain why I would need to use `| grep ^[0-9] | xargs -r -n1`?  

Using either one or the other example, I get a bunch errors.  

Instead, using `ssh-keyscan -H -p 10022 $(dig -t a +short domain.tld)` I get what it seems to be a legit result.  

In fact, just `dig -t a +short domain.tld` returns a single IP address.

Comment: I meant to mention you, but apparently I failed: that's a second attempt :) @RichAlloway

Comment: No problem @AndreaSciamanna !  The `| grep ^[0-9]` only uses the IPs returned by dig (if a hostname starts with a number, the grep would need to be modified to better identify IPs).   When testing with www.yahoo.com, I get two IPs and 'fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com.', which is the CNAME for www.yahoo.com, in the dig output.  ssh-keyscan appears to behave with the trailing period, but I wanted to exclude the CNAME.  The `| xargs -r -n1` creates one execution of ssh-keyscan per result, but doesn't execute ssh-keyscan at all if there are no results.